# See web history for specific websites in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, history

Is it possible to show all web history in Google Chrome for a specific website? I tried entering `site:commons.wikipedia.org` on the history page to see all history from that domain, but it returned no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I met with the same problem a few days ago, and I'm afraid Chrome's default history page doesn't come with such functionality.
 
The best solution I found out is to install an extension called 'better history'
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb
Just search for the domain (type 'https://superuser.com' then press Enter) then click 'delete', chrome will ask you whether you really want to delete all search results, click 'delete' then it is done.
There is a question I am not able to figure out, however. As you can see, all history records are devided by week (the list on the left side), like  Sep.24, Sep.17, Sep.10... I accidently delete all my history last week so I only have history of this week in my chrome. As a result, I don't know whether the extension only searches that domain within this week, or searches all history. You can have a try at your side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching `site:commons.wikipedia.org`, just type the URL. This returns all sites from that URL, in addition to a few other sites.

Comment: Yes, it works reasonably well, but I'd like to exclude those "other sites" so that I won't accidentally delete anything.